# How to display rspec errors faster?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

My rspec test suite is slow. It takes about half a decade to run all the tests. While it's running, I see only that tests are failing.

```
.......................................................................
.......FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF....F..........FFFFFFFFF.........................
................FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.....................FF.................
..........................FFF..........................................
.............FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF....................................
................................................................FFFF...
.......FFFFFFFFF..........................
```

Then, after staring at this for a few years, I finally get a listing of what is wrong.

```
Failures:

  172481) Foobar should barfoo the barbaz while quux is set to narf
     Failure/Error: before { click_link "Enable narf" }
     ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
     # ./app/helpers/foobar_helper.rb:22:in `gobble'
     # ./app/controllers/barbaz_controller.rb:18:in `omgwtf'
     # (eval):2:in `click_link'
     # ./spec/requests/metasyntactic_spec.rb:43:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Is there a way to tell rspec it should display the errors directly - **while running the test suite?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the fuubar format, see the doc here : https://github.com/jeffkreeftmeijer/fuubar/

Comment: Great! It even displays an ETA! Testing is fun again! :)

Comment: Please, approve the answer if you agree.